# Combine same keys in dictionary ignoring case

Tags: python, dictionary, case-insensitive

I've looked and looked but could not find an answer to my question. How can I combine dictionaries keys ignoring their case.
For example say I have a dictionary like this.

```
dict = {'a':1,'A',2}
```

Ignoring the case, these two keys are the same alphabet. Therefor I would like the combine them to end up with a dictionary that would look something like this

```
dict = {'a':3}
```

The case of the outputs key does not matter.

---

Currently my code looks like this.

```
s = "YazaAay"
freq = {i : s.count(i) for i in set(s)}
```

And this will return me with

```
{'A': 1, 'z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}
```

My desired output would be this

```
{'a':4,'z':1,'y':2}
```

#Neither case nor order matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution to case-folding is generally to just call `lower()` (or `upper()`) on the string.

I'd also suggest using `collections.Counter` instead of building your own logic to count the letters; it's more efficient (since it only loops through the string once, whereas your solution using `set()` and `count()` loops through it once per unique letter plus once at the start to build the set) and it makes your code simpler.

```
>>> s = "YazaAay"
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(s.lower())
Counter({'a': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 1})
```

If you were starting from the dictionary instead of the string, one option would be to just turn the dictionary back into a string with `join()` and then apply the exact same solution with `.lower()` and `Counter`:

```
>>> d = {'A': 1, 'z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}
>>> collections.Counter(''.join(k * v for k, v in d.items()).lower())
Counter({'a': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Comment: Yes, I should have included I was looking for something using `collections`. But for other users who have the same question I guess it would be simple to get a variety of questions. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here A Solution without Using Imports.

```
s = "YazaAay".lower()
freq = {i: s.count(i) for i in sorted(s)}
```

output:

```
{'a': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 1}
```

Comment: Not that it matters too much for a string this small, but this is even less efficient than OP's original solution with `set()`; it's now O(len(s)**2) instead of O(len(s) * len(set(s))).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, lowering the string beforehand would circumvent your problem.

```
s = "YazaAay"
freq = {i : s.count(i) for i in set(s.lower())}
```

In the more general case if you already have a mixed-case dict, you could rebuild with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'A': 1, 'z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}

new_dict = defaultdict(int)
for key, val in d.items():
    new_dict[key.lower()] += val
```

which would give you

```
defaultdict(int, {'a': 4, 'z': 1, 'y': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple solution.**

```
# Original dictionary
d = {'A': 1, 'z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}
```

```
# Split the dictionary into 2 parts
lower_case_keys = dict((key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key.islower())
Output: {'z': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}

upper_case_keys = dict((key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key.isupper())
Output: {'A': 1, 'Y': 1}
```

```
# Convert lower_case_keys to upper case for uniformity
lower_case_keys_to_upper_case = dict((key.upper(), value) for key, value in d.items())
output: {'A': 3, 'Z': 1, 'Y': 1}
```

```
from collections import Counter
final_dict = dict(Counter(lower_case_keys_to_upper_case) + Counter(upper_case_keys))
Output: {'A': 4, 'Z': 1, 'Y': 2}
```

**All of this can be combined into a function.**

```
from collections import Counter
def get_case_insensitive_sum(d):
    lower_case_keys = dict((key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key.islower())
    upper_case_keys = dict((key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key.isupper())
    lower_case_keys_to_upper_case = dict((key.upper(), value) for key, value in d.items())
    final_dict = dict(Counter(lower_case_keys_to_upper_case) + Counter(upper_case_keys))
    print(final_dict)
```

```
d = {'A': 1, 'z': 1, 'Y': 1, 'a': 3, 'y': 1}
get_case_insensitive_sum(d)
Output: {'A': 4, 'Z': 1, 'Y': 2}
```

Comment: If you're starting from the dictionary, you can turn it into a case-folded string by just doing `''.join(key * value for key, value in d.items()).lower()`.  :)  No reason to split it in two only to recombine them later!